# Can't figure out how to change "JOHN" to "John"

Tags: c++, string

This needs to be a C++ program:

> Write a complete C program to enter a first name, middle name and last name in separate variables.  The user is to enter the names in all capital letters.  You are to write a function to convert the names to uppercase first letter, rest of the letters lower case.  Combine the names into one string and output the string (make sure you have a space between each name).  Count the number of characters (including spaces) in the total name and output that.

I'm not familiar with strings much and could use some guidance as to where to start.

Comment: you might find this reference page useful (assuming you know some C++ but not strings): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ Actual examples here: http://anaturb.net/C/string_exapm.htm

Comment: C or C++?  assignment says C, your comment and the tag says C++.  Model answers for each will be very different.

Comment: Please follow [general](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) question [guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812), state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you need [std::string](http://microsoft.com/en-us/library/xabz5s9c.aspx) and [std::tolower](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt62k3xy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), [std::toupper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fk4ystc.aspx).

In C this will rely on [string manipulation in the CRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0151s4x.aspx) (C runtime library).

Since this is homework, that should get you going, if you get stuck post again.

Comment: Can i get a C++ example for this. Like if the person typed

Comment: that comment was messed up ^ i meant to ask if the program asked someone for their names in all caps and they put: JACOB HENREY ADAMS I want the output of it to be : Jacob Henrey Adams. Could I please get a tiny writen out chunk of just that part of the program, I still dont know how to write this out in C++ it's the only part i can't figure out now. Thanks

Comment: @matt - nobody here is going to do your homework for you.  Post what you have once you have had a go, and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can try:

Note that characters can be represented as integers. If you check the [ascii table](http://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+table) you can do addition and subtraction with the characters in your string.

So if you do for instance:

```
char aChar = 'a';
char afterChar = aChar+1;
cout << "a+1 = " << afterChar << endl;
```

you'll get 'b' printed. If you fiddle with that, I think you'll be able to do what you want.